# Advert not display in Website, but in DFP it shows as Delivering

Tags: google-dfp

I am a New DFP User. I have added two adverts for my different sites. In DFP, adverts shows as delivering, but still now my advert is not placed in my site. what can i do next? why my advert is not displaying? Please reply me and explain what mistake i have done? 
waiting for your kind response.

i herewith attached my Site & DFP screenshot with this. Kindly refer this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

in inspect-element of my site, it shows the below  code.. but it seems to hidden!

```
<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/41172323/Thakkali_Test_0__hidden__" name="google_ads_iframe_/41172323/Thakkali_Test_0__hidden__" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can do is help you help yourself. Adtech is complicated, lots of moving parts, lots of places where a small error can cause big and unpredictable problems. I don't see any obvious problems in the information that you provided but there can still be problems with tagging or targeting. You have 442 criteria for targeting the line item, big chance that the problem is there.

But to check this you can use the GPT console. Enable this by by adding:

?google_force_console

to the URL when loading your site. This tells you if you have correctly tagged the page and you can also open 'Delivery diagnostics' which gives you an overview line items that where considered/rejected for a specific ad unit.

More information about the GPT console:

https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/181070?hl=en

Besides that; be patient. There is a time lag between DFP telling you that it's delivering and the actual delivery. Changes are rarely instantaneous with DFP.